Pex A 1/2'' Tube Fits into 1/2'' PEX fitting without expansion
I have a 1/2'' PEX to 3/8'' Comp Adapter link

However, when I am trying to fit it into a 1/2'' PEX A Tube (expansion needed).It goes straight in without any expansion!.

For the pipe, I use a PEX-A 1/2'' Inner Diameter (ID), and 5/8'' Outside Diameter (OD). In this case, what adapter should I use to adapt the tube into 3/8'' Comp (NTP)?
Update
The adapters we used are
PEX-A 1/2" <> MNPT 1/2" link
FIP 1/2" <> 3/8" MNPT link

That's a PEX-B fitting intended for a crimp connection. You need a PEX-A fitting for an expansion connection. They have different shapes and dimensions. PEX-A has a ring of a larger diameter with a sharp edge, PEX-B fittings have multiple rings of a smaller diameter with no sharp edges.
PEX-A fitting:

PEX-B fitting:

Images credit: pexuniverse.com

Excellent explanation of the difference between Pex A and B fittings.  The pics help tremendously.  This should be hanging everywhere that sells Pex.
